# common lisp . cond in defun

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

i`m making a insert list function. it look like :

```
(defun INSERT1 (x y)
(setq temp (list x y))
(setq k (sort temp #'< :key #'car)))

(defun INSERT2 (x y)
(setq temp (cons x y))
(setq k (sort temp #'< :key #'car)))
```

and i have to combine these two function.
first insert function works when there`s nothing in 'k'. and second insertcell function work when there were any elements in 'k'.

i thought i need to use 'cond', and i thought 'cond' is

```
(cond ((true/false)if true execute here and return)
      ((true/false)if true execute here and return)
      ......
      ((true/false)if true execute here and return))
```

so i made this:

```
(defun INSERT1 (x y)
(setq temp (list x y))
(setq k (sort temp #'< :key #'car)))

(defun INSERT2 (x y)
(setq temp (cons x y))
(setq k (sort temp #'< :key #'car)))

(defun INSERTCELL (x y)
(setq temp nil)
(cond
((eq (car temp) nil) (INSERT1 (x y))
(t (INSERT2 (x y))))))
```

and error :

```
*** - EVAL: undefined function X
```

how can i use 'cond' at this problem with no errors...

please teach me the correct code.

Comment: `(INSERT1 (x y))` should be `(INSERT1 x y) `, otherwise `x` is interpreted as a function applied to `y`.

Comment: oh.. thanks Renzo. it works now.

Answer (score 0):

In Common Lisp (and other lisps in general), `(foo ...)` always mean one of:

- Call the function FOO
- Expand the macro FOO
- Do something with the special operator FOO

If you're used to a non-lisp programming language, what you would normally write as `foo(...)` is written `(foo ...)`.